# Find coordinates that are outside a radius

Tags: python-3.x

I'm a beginner with Python. I need to get the number of arrows (points) that are outside the radius. I do know what the answer is, but how do I get that output in Python?

This is what I have:

```
points = [(4, 5), (-0, 2), (4, 7), (1, -3), (3, -2), (4, 5), (3, 2), (5, 7), (-5, 7), (2, 2), (-4, 5), (0, -2),(-4, 7), (-1, 3), (-3, 2), (-4, -5), (-3, 2), (5, 7), (5, 7), (2, 2), (9, 9), (-8, -9)]
center = (0,0)
radius = 9
```

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
import math

points = [(4, 5), (-0, 2), (4, 7), (1, -3), (3, -2), (4, 5), (3, 2), (5, 7),
          (-5, 7), (2, 2), (-4, 5), (0, -2), (-4, 7), (-1, 3), (-3, 2), (-4, -5),
          (-3, 2), (5, 7), (5, 7), (2, 2), (9, 9), (-8, -9)]
center = (0, 0)
radius = 9

points_outside_radius = [
    p 
    for p in points 
    if math.sqrt((p[0] - center[0]) ** 2 + (p[1] - center[1]) ** 2) > radius
]
num_points_outside_radius = len(points_outside_radius)
print(f'There are {num_points_outside_radius} points outside the radius:')
print(points_outside_radius)
```

**Output:**

```
There are 2 points outside the radius:
[(9, 9), (-8, -9)]
```

*Note I used the full [euclidian distance formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) in case you need to change the center to something other than the origin.*